# How can I convert Npp8u * to CUdeviceptr

Tags: api, cuda, driver, npp

I am new to cuda driver Api interface but I think that CUdeviceptr looks like a handle parameter.So I confused about the convertion between CUdeviceptr and npp8u *.

```
Npp8u * src;
......
unsigned char temp;
temp = src;
CUdeviceptr devPtr;
.......
devPtr = (CUdeviceptr)temp;
```

I try to write the convertion like above,is that right!

Answer (score 4):

`cuDevicePtr` is, in fact, a raw pointer, not a handle. You can see the original architect of the CUDA driver and driver API discuss this [here](http://blog.cudahandbook.com/2013/08/12/why-does-cuda-cudeviceptr-use-unsigned-int-instead-of-void.aspx) (and school me in the process). So if you have an existing "typed" device pointer, it is safe to cast it to a `cuDevicePtr`, or vice versa, for example:

```
cuDevicePtr m;
cuMemAlloc(&m, size);

Npp8U* p = (Npp8U*)(m);
// Pass p to NPP library functions...
```

is legal and should work.

Comment: Thanks,it complied successfully.But "Npp8U* p = (Npp8U*)(m)",p is error pointer.In the other hand,I have tried "Npp*p = *(Npp8u **)&m",it also complied successfully and that p is error pointer.

Comment: @user2968731: Then you are doing something wrong. WIthout seeing a concrete example I cannot tell you what.

Answer (score 2):

By demoting the pointer to `unsigned char` before converting to `CUdeviceptr`, you are masking off all but the least significant 8 bits of `src`.

Just write:

`Npp8u *src;`
`CUdeviceptr devPtr = (CUdeviceptr) (uintptr_t) src;`

Answer (score -1):

Typically you wouldn't do this explicitly, but rather cast Npp8u* to a void ** when passing to cudaMalloc:

```
Npp8u * src;
int length = ...
cudaMalloc( (void **)(&src), sizeof( Npp8u ) * length );
```

Comment: The question is specifically about the driver API. `cudaMalloc` is not a driver API call.

Comment: @kunzmi HeyBro！Do you have any idea about that？